# Is the phrase order in this sentence correct?

Tags: grammar

This is an extract from an interview:

女： 现代五项这个项目最早在哪个国家推广的？
男： 这个项目起源于欧洲，最早在瑞典推广的这个项目。

He did *not* say: 最早于欧洲起源的这个项目

So why did he say: 最早在瑞典推广的这个项目 ？？

The phrase order seems odd to me, 这个老外. Is it odd?

The best answer I have so far is: 'He is a sportsman, sportsmen are not necessarily good at talking. He would not write this way.'

Edit: The bit that confuses me is '的这个项目’ tacked on the end, seems strange to me, because he already said '这个项目起源于欧洲,'. I see no point or purpose in saying '这个项目' at the end.

I did a search for ’的这个‘。 I found 1, which I think is OK when I rearrange it as 2. From the others, I only like 7.

1. 法国西南部的这个地区是干红葡萄酒的产地。
2. 这个法国西南部的地区是干红葡萄酒的产地。
3. 这个项目起源于欧洲，最早在瑞典推广的这个项目。
4. 这个项目起源于欧洲，这个最早在瑞典推广的项目。
5. 这个项目起源于欧洲，最早在瑞典这个推广的项目。
6. 这个项目起源于欧洲，这个项目最早在瑞典推广的。
7. 这个项目起源于欧洲，最早在瑞典推广的。

Comment: I am not sure what part(s) really confuse you?

Comment: I didn't get your question, but I agree that this sentence is weird; the more natural way might be `这个项目起源于欧洲，最早在瑞典推广。`, or `这是个起源于欧洲，最早在瑞典推广的项目。`.

Comment: It simply lost a comma. It should be “最早在瑞典推广的，这个项目” = “这个项目最早在瑞典推广的”. An inverted sentence.

Comment: @Pedroski he's just speaking as he's thinking - probably didn't formulate the order very well before opening his mouth

Answer (score 2):

It is not odd.

项目 is the subject of 起源 (and cannot be used an object), but the object of 推广 (and probably cannot be used as subject).

We can say 项目推广, but this is used as noun phrase which means the "the promotion of the event". It is like a short form of 项目的推广, where 推广 is a noun.

"现代五项这个项目最早在哪个国家推广的？" This may be treated as implicit passive voice, "现代五项这个项目最早在哪个国家（被）推广的？"

Answer (score 1):

Under this particular circumstance you are talking about, "最早在瑞典推广的这个项目" is actually the same as "这个项目最早是在瑞典推广的” which sounds more natural to native ears. In most cases, everything that is before the character "的” is attributive. So "最早在瑞典推广的这个项目" would, without any context, mean "the project that was first promoted in Sweden". Hope you like my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You got it right. '的这个项目’ is redundant.

So, a better version is:

> 这个项目起源于欧洲，最早在瑞典推广。

You don't have to put 的 at the end of 最早在瑞典推广, because 推广 is used as a verb.

"法国西南部的这个地区是干红葡萄酒的产地。" sounds better than "这个法国西南部的地区是干红葡萄酒的产地。" It's because we take 这个地区 as a whole. 法国西南部的 modifies 这个地区.